# Duplicates using while loop and search algorithm

Tags: c++, vector, containers

```
for (int j = 0; j < messageVector.size(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bookVector.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t offset = 0;
        while ((offset = bookVector[i].find(messageVector[j], offset)) != string::npos)
        {
                cout << "Found " << messageVector[j] << " at " << i << "," << offset << std::endl;
                ++offset;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem i'm having with this code is that if the bookvector contains a duplicate letter the letter will be printed both times with both positions. so if the messageVector contained the message "test" but the bookvector contained the alphabet with an extra t, the output would be: found t at i,offset two times and then the rest of the message. This isn't necessarily a problem but I would like for duplicate letters to be only printed once with a random set of coordinates where a t was found being chosen.

I was thinking of a way to solve the problem, I basically have it done in pseudocode, I was going to get all the rows and offset that have the same character, put them in a container, pick a random one. print the found positions to the console with the character, clear the container and move on to the next letter and do it all over again. However I don't know where to do this in the while loop. If someone could help walk me through it it would be nice.

sample output is

```
Found H at 1,0
Found H at 3,9
Found E at 0,4
Found L at 1,4
Found L at 1,4
Found O at 1,7
```

bookVector is

ABCDE FG,
HIJKLMNO,
PQRSTUVWXYZ,
TDASDGKSDH

MessageVector is 
H,E,L,L,O

Comment: So your problem comes wether bookVector contains duplicated letters? Either use a bool to end the while and inner for loop as soon as the first match is found, or copy your bookVector into a set, which will get rid of duplicates, and use that instead of bookVector

Comment: I cannot use sets since bookVector is a vector of lines, if I put bookVector into a set it won't get rid of duplicate characters but duplicate lines. I need the vector of lines in order to keep track of the row number and offset number of the character

Comment: then just exit as you find the first occurrence

Comment: where would I put the break and what would be the criteria for the break. I tried doing if oldoffset == offset and  if oldrow == j then break but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Declare a bool variable before the inner for loop: `bool found = false;`. The inner for loop condition becomes `i < bookVector.size() && !found`. Inside while loop, `found = true; break;`

Comment: you are amazing thank you I was stuck on this for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

you should keep track of letters you already found, which can be done by using 
before looking for the letter check it in the set, if exists you can skip this letter. if not add it to the set and start looking in the bookVector.